# Desktop shortcut to exe on network share disappears if network dies

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, shortcuts

On Windows 7, shortcuts on the desktop will disappear if the LAN drops out for a few minutes. This has been reported to me by multiple users over multiple incidents.

These shortcuts are to EXEs on a UNC network share. There is no AD domain, so these shortcuts have UAC shields on them. Shortcuts to the network share itself do not disappear.

I can only imagine that this is expected behavior. When the network drops out, these shortcut icons disappear from the desktop, and they do not reappear when the network comes back online. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Remove the `DELETE` permission on the shortcut to the user accounts that they are on or just apply `READ` permission to these only. Otherwise, look at putting the shortcuts in the "public" profile desktop folder on the PCs rather than the desktop of each profile explicitly. You might also consider figuring out a way to have the shortcut created or copied from another location at login, and if this happens, tell the end-user to logoff and back on once network connection is reestablished.

Comment: I'd emulate the network outage from one of these PCs yourself to confirm this is occurring as well. Simply get it all setup on a profile with the same level of permissions as the end-user, and then pull the Ethernet plug. I would think when it's not available, the shortcut is clicked, it states it's missing or invalid do you wish to remove, and it's only removed if that option is selected and thus removing the permission to delete or remove the invalid shortcut when network is down would resolve.

Comment: Can the missing icons be made to reappear by a simple press of `F5` while the Desktop has the focus?